# Shoot bullet to direction of last player position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to code a drone that is shooting a laser-bullet to the last position of the player. The bullet should also rotate to the players position.

I have following script, but it is not shooting for some reason.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroneShoot: MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform bulletspawn;
    public Rigidbody2D bulletPrefab;
    public float bulletSpeed = 750;
    public float bulletDelay;

    private Transform player;
    private Rigidbody2D clone;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("spieler").GetComponent<Transform>();
    StartCoroutine(Attack());
    }

    IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(bulletDelay);
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, bulletspawn.transform.position) < 20)
        {
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.transform.position, bulletspawn.transform.position);
            bulletspawn.rotation = rotation;
            clone = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletspawn.position, bulletspawn.rotation);

            clone.AddForce(bulletspawn.transform.right * bulletSpeed);
            StartCoroutine(Attack());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it would be helpful to know exactly what your bullets are doing... do they have a script on them?  What collision Layer are they on? What collision layer is your drone on? is it possible your bullet is colliding with your drone?

Comment: I have disabled the collider of the drone. The bullet has 2 scripts (destroy after 2 seconds and deal damage when colliding with player).

The bullet spawns now, but it is not visible (layer is high enough). It also has a rotation, but for some reason I can't see the bullet. And it is very small. I update my script in the main question.

Comment: Alright what are those scripts? and what is your shoot delay?

Comment: are there errors in the console or does it shoot just once?

Comment: My shoot delay is 2 seconds. The scripts on the bullet is as I mentioned: Destroying the bullet 2 seconds after being spawned and dealing damage when colliding with player. There are no errors. It shoots multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroneShoot: MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform bulletspawn;
public Rigidbody2D bulletPrefab;
public float bulletSpeed = 750;
public float bulletDelay;

private Transform player;
private Rigidbody2D clone;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("spieler").GetComponent<Transform>();
    StartCoroutine(Attack());
}

IEnumerator Attack()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(bulletDelay);
    if (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, bulletspawn.transform.position) < 20)
    {

        Vector3 difference = player.position - bulletspawn.position;
        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        bulletspawn.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);

        clone = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletspawn.position, bulletspawn.rotation);

        clone.AddForce(bulletspawn.transform.right * bulletSpeed);
        StartCoroutine(Attack());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *`I have a solution.`* Cool. Mind explaining it?

Comment: The problem was, that the bullets rotation only changed the x- and y-axis. I have 2D game, so I only had to change the z-axis. That's why the bullet was so small and had the wrong direction/rotation. Still I can't explain that variable rotationZ and Quaternion.Euler. I got a the code from the web.

Comment: `rotationZ` is the angle between your bullet and the player. `Quaternion.Euler` converts a Euler angle (x, y, and z rotation) into a Quaternion (w, x, y, and z rotation).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will only try to fire again if it is able to fire the first time because StartCoroutine is inside the distance check.

I think it should keep trying to shoot forever.

```
IEnumerator Attack()
{
    while(true){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(shootDelay);
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, bulletspawn.transform.position) < 20)
        {
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.transform.position);
            bulletspawn.rotation = rotation;
            clone = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletspawn.position, bulletspawn.rotation);

            clone.AddForce(bulletspawn.transform.right * bulletSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the bullet is small and not visible and very slow. Changing the bulletSpeed is not changing the speed for some reason.

Comment: Make sure the bullet prefab is correct.  The prefab should be the only thing controlling the bullet size.

Comment: Yes it is. Before I started to use "LookRotation", everything was fine. The drone was shooting left and right and I could see them aswell.

Comment: Another thing to think about is maybe the bullet is actually moving too fast, but is only visible for one frame because of its high speed, and it is firing so many bullets it looks like only one.

Comment: It is definitely shooting only 1 bullet per 2 seconds. I am pretty sure, that the rotation method is wrong. The bullet rotates, but it is not rotating towards the player somehow.

Comment: Ah LookRotation is also incorrect.  It aligns the rotation with a direction vector.  You should use `Transform.LookAt`, or `Quaternion.LookRotation(bulletspawn.transform.position - player.transform.position)` or in your bullet behavior, you could do `Quaternion.LookAt(rigidbody.Velocity)` in Update

Comment: Yay, I can see the bullet, pretty small for some reason, but ok. I think I have to fix the sprite, so the rotation works properly. Only problem now is, that the bullet is only shooting to the right. Is there a method where I can shoot to the direction of the player without putting it into Update() ?